# Android - Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name

Tags: android, facebook

I am using share dialog of facebook in order to share a link from my app to facebook. But I keep getting error `com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name.`

I already made my app status live and available to public.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue, this is how I solved it for me.
The solution was to add .setApplicationName("name of app")

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
        .setLink("https://www.google.com")
        .setApplicationName("name of app")
        .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Answer (score 3):

You may check your developer roles or disable the Sandbox Mode.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue in android emulator.

I restarted the emulator and works fine. Its may be because of network not available.