# FacebookDialog: Do I need to implement login?

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented a FacebookDialog in my app, and it is working...in most cases.

```
 if(FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(activity,FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
                    .setLink(activity.getString(R.string.link_to_app_store))
                    .build();

            shareDialog.present();
        }
```

However, I've noticed that some Facebook accounts do not work with it, because these accounts are not linked to my app in their permission page. How this is the case, I do not know. What I do know is that the above code will result in the user being directed to the native app for login when they do not have a session. It will not however request app permissions when the user has an active session but has not granted basic permissions to the app.

This creates a situation where the app is presented momentarily, but then is hiding as the app does not have permissions to publish.

My question then, is do I need to implement login, or is there a way to handle the case where a user has not granted my app permission?

Comment: Is your App id a test id or is it live ?

Comment: No, you do not need to implement login for the dialogs to work.

Comment: @MingLi what is your source and how do you handle the case where the user has not granted your app permissions?

Comment: Source: I work on the SDK and wrote some of the share dialog feature. Using the share dialog does not require login. It should launch the share dialog from the Facebook app if installed (otherwise canPresentShareDialog will return false). If you're seeing a flash and then nothing, then there's some other error going on (like your app not being public).

Comment: @MingLi turns out it was a seperate issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374579/android-error-com-facebook-facebookexception-failed-to-get-app-name. Silly that we have to do that. Also, it should be in the guide.

Comment: hmm, setApplicationName should just be an optimization, and should not be a requirement. Are you testing this in an emulator or device? What version of the Facebook app are you using?

Comment: This was seen on 24.0.0.30.15 on a S4, Note 3, and S5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, this turned out to be due to an error being returned by Facebook. Looking in the log's the error stated "app name not found." This was strangely only occurring on certain users accounts and not account wide.

The fix? Setting the application name via `.setApplicationName` on the `ShareDialog`.